# Flutter - error no such file or directory when reading JSON file

Tags: json, dart, flutter

Hi so I am trying to convert JSON to objects but when I read the file it throws up an exception:

> FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'D:/AndroidStudio/my_app/assets/data/questions.json' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

here is the code:

```
String loadQuestionAsset() {
  String jsonString;
  new File('D:/AndroidStudio/my_app/assets/data/questions.json').readAsString().then((String contents) {
    jsonString = contents;
  });
  return jsonString;
}
List<Question> parseJsonForQuestion() {
  Map decoded = jsonDecode(loadQuestionAsset());
  List<Question> questions = new List<Question>();
  for (var question in decoded['questions']) {
    questions.add(new Question(question['question'], question['bool']));
  }
  return questions;
}
```

and the JSON file:

```
{
  "questions": [
    {
      "question": "Elon Musk is human",
      "bool": false
    },
    {
      "question": "Pizza is healthy",
      "bool": false
    },
    {
      "question": "Flutter is awesome",
      "bool": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

Path you need to provide is: `assets/data/questions.json`.

Now, in order to read it, you have to add this also into assets in `pubspec.yaml` file.

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - data/questions.json
```

Then, in order to read, you should use [rootBundle](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/rootBundle.html):

```
Map map = await rootBundle
  .loadStructuredData('assets/data/questions.json', (String s) async {
     return json.decode(s);
  });
```

I hope it works :)

Comment: Thank you very much for help, but I just cant get it working. I did what you said, but now it returns **Future<List<Question>>** instead of **<List<Question>**. How would I go about that?

Comment: That's because it is an asynchronous function. Are you sure you didn't remove `await` keyword? Anyway, I recommend you reading on how asynchronous functions work in Dart: https://www.dartlang.org/articles/language/await-async. It will probably solve your issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
String loadQuestionAsset() {
  String jsonString;
  File('D:/AndroidStudio/my_app/assets/data/questions.json').create().readAsString().then(String contents) {
    jsonString = contents;
  });
  return jsonString;
}
```